# Wpf Combobox selectedindex shows old value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox with two different bindings.

```
                <ComboBox Canvas.Left="194" Canvas.Top="101" Width="80" Height="30" FontWeight="Normal" SelectedIndex="0">
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={x:Static my:DesignBinding.Instance},Path=AuxCoilWire,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ConfigDataPrimaryWire}, XPath=copperWires/copperWire/add[1]/@value}"/>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
```

ComboboxItem gets a value from another window and always updates itself via the propertyChanged method

```
    public class DesignBinding : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly DesignBinding instance = new DesignBinding();
    private DesignBinding() { }

    public static DesignBinding Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    private double auxCoilWire;
    public double AuxCoilWire
    {
        get { return auxCoilWire; }
        set { auxCoilWire = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("AuxCoilWire"); }
    }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
```

The code actually works, the combo box gets the new value, but shows me selectedindex = "0" still the old value.
I have to open the dropdown menu to update the value.
Then everything works, the combobox only shows the new value.
How can I update the value immediately without having to open the dropdown menu?
I have already searched for a few hours and tried, but found no decent solution :(

Answer (score 0):

okay, I have a very bad solution. I created a load event handler and then set the IsDropDownOpen property to true and then false again.
I'm looking for too long ..

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that your binding only applies to the *content*?. If you are not selecting anything by the GUI, then you are only updating the dropdown menu.

Unless you select an item, the *selecteditem* property will not change. You should call the event or force Combobox.selecteditem in the code if that's the case.